# Android Studio Fall 2018 which JDK for Ubuntu 16/18?

Tags: java, android, jdk

As Android seems to change all the time I put the date into the question title.

I've just installed Android Studio which is current as of October 15, 2018 and burned up 2 GB of SSD space. According to [Lifewire Instructions](https://www.lifewire.com/install-android-studio-for-linux-4056779) I need to install JDK from Oracle next.

So I run:

```
$ apt search jdk | wc -l

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

311
```

Too many to list but, here is a sample:

```
openjdk-8-jdk/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

openjdk-8-jdk-headless/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)

openjdk-8-jre/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
  OpenJDK Java runtime, using Hotspot JIT

openjdk-9-jdk/xenial 9~b114-0ubuntu1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

openjdk-9-dbg/xenial 9~b114-0ubuntu1 amd64
  Java runtime based on OpenJDK (debugging symbols)

openjdk-9-jdk-headless/xenial 9~b114-0ubuntu1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK) (headless)
```

JDK version 8 reports `8u181` in the Ubuntu listing. The **Lifewire** article says if `8U181` and `8U182` are available to pick `8u182`. However JDK version 9 in Ubuntu doesn't mention 8U182 or 8U181.

```
$ apt search jdk | grep -i 8U181

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

oracle-java8-installer/xenial,xenial,now 8u181-1~webupd8~1 all [installed]
Oracle Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 8
openjdk-8-demo/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all
openjdk-8-jdk/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-jdk-headless/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-jre/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-jre-headless/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-jre-jamvm/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-jre-zero/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
openjdk-8-source/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 all
oracle-java8-installer/xenial,xenial,now 8u181-1~webupd8~1 all [installed]
oracle-java8-set-default/xenial,xenial,now 8u181-1~webupd8~1 all [installed]
```

Which of the following should I run?

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer # already installed
sudo apt install oracle-java9-installer
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt install openjdk-9-jdk
```

Or should I be running a combination or something different?

Comment: @tudor `apt search jdk-9` returns 8 results.  The fourth one is: `openjdk-9-jdk/xenial 9~b114-0ubuntu1 amd64
  OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)` I have enabled other repositories such as `Partner` and `Universe` if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio is based upon the IntelliJ IDEA codebase.  The documentation for which says [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879):

> It's recommended to use the bundled JRE (if available). In case you
>   have any issues with the bundled version, you can switch to the latest
>   Oracle JDK or OpenJDK 1.8 build available on your system (JDK 1.8 is
>   recommended and older Java versions are not supported starting from
>   IntelliJ IDEA 16).

So, it appears at least since version 16, the JRE is bundled with Android Studio.  It also says:

> ...Our custom JRE is based on OpenJDK...

However, I remember when I first installed Android Studio a while back, during setup there was a dialog box that explained that it could get more features from the Oracle JDK. and encouraged you to install it.  This is probably old news now, though.

It's actually relatively easy to change this after the installation as well, so I wouldn't worry too much about which one you choose early on as you can always change it later.

Comment: I just went through the normal installation and configuration of Android Studio and there was no mention about JDK needing to be installed. So your answer seems to be correct.